# Density function of a certain random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables of exponential distribution with parameter $1$.

Put: $Z = max(X,Y)$.

How would we find the density function of $Z$?

This type of problems is new to me, and I don't know about the usual methods for tackling such problems. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by trying to find the (cumulative) distribution function of $Z$. We have
$$F_{Z}(z) = \mathbb{P}\left(Z \leq z\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\max(X,Y) \leq z\right)\text{.}$$
If $\max(X,Y)\leq z$, then $X \leq z$ and $Y \leq z$. So 
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\max(X,Y) \leq z\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(X \leq z \cap Y \leq z\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(X \leq z\right)\mathbb{P}\left(Y \leq z\right)\text{,}$$
due to independence. So therefore, $$F_{Z}(z) = \mathbb{P}\left(X \leq z\right)\mathbb{P}\left(Y \leq z\right)$$
and the derivative of a continuous cumulative distribution function is the probability density function, so all you need to find is $$f_{Z}(z) = \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z}\left[\mathbb{P}\left(X \leq z\right)\mathbb{P}\left(Y \leq z\right)\right]\text{.}$$
I leave the details to you.